# Set application version in SCDF from Java DSL

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

I'm trying to deploy a stream using Java DSL.

Here the code that creates stream (fluent style)

```java
    private void create() {
        builder
                .name(this.STREAM_NAME)
                .source(source)
                .sink(sink)
                .create();
    }
```

deployment method

```java
    private void deploy() {
        dataFlowOperations.streamOperations().deploy(this.STREAM_NAME, new HashMap());
        waitForStatus("deployed");
    }
```

and a method that creates a bean for source application

```java
    @Bean
    public StreamApplication source() {
        return new StreamApplication("httpsource")
                .addProperty("app.httpsource.version", "0.0.17")
                .addProperty("spring.cloud.dataflow.httpsource.validation.schema", this.properties.getHttpSource().getJsonSchema());

    }
```

I first trigger `create` method, then `deploy`. The problem is - I want to set application version to `0.0.17` for httpsource application, but final pod that is deployed for this app has image version equal to default version `0.0.1`. Is it possible to set application version with Java DSL?

Answer (score 0):

When deploying streams/tasks, optionally, you can pass in the version parameters as part of the deployment properties. Specifically, for versions, you'd pass them with the `version.<APP_NAME>` convention.

The `DataflowIT` presents such test combinations (see: [sample](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/blob/main/spring-cloud-dataflow-server/src/test/java/org/springframework/cloud/dataflow/integration/test/DataFlowIT.java#L447-L454)); feel free to use it for reference.  We rely on these tests for IT and as well as end-to-end Acceptance Tests.